# I need to store values from a for loop into an array

Tags: arrays, vba

Basically I am required to prompt the user for values in relation to the sunshine totals for the first quarter of three years.

---

I have my main form with a button that says "Start".

When this button is clicked i want a prompt box to open. This prompt box should prompt the user for 9 values which are split across the three years. E.g

```
"Please enter the total sunshine for January 2011"
"Please enter the total sunshine for February 2011"
"Please enter the total sunshine for March 2011"

"Please enter the total sunshine for January 2012"
"Please enter the total sunshine for February 2012"
"Please enter the total sunshine for March 2012"

"Please enter the total sunshine for January 2013"
"Please enter the total sunshine for February 2013"
"Please enter the total sunshine for March 2013"
```

I need to store the values in seperate arrays. Therefore the inputted values that correspond with each of the three years should be included within an array of their own.

Comment: what programmming language are you using?

Comment: i am using visual basic

Comment: sorry haven't experience with that one

Answer (score 0):

The following code will provide a *solution* to what you want. Since I have no idea what you will do with the values after they are entered, I urge you to: (a) save them to a table or something; (b) add code to handle non-numeric values (i.e. retry).  If I was a user and I had to answer 9 questions every time I ran a routine, I would not be very happy...

```
Sub Get_Sunshine_Values()
Dim a2011(3) As Double
Dim a2012(3) As Double
Dim a2013(3) As Double

a2011(1) = InputBox("Please enter the total sunshine for January 2011", "Sunshine")
a2011(2) = InputBox("Please enter the total sunshine for February 2011", "Sunshine")
a2011(3) = InputBox("Please enter the total sunshine for March 2011", "Sunshine")

a2012(1) = InputBox("Please enter the total sunshine for January 2012", "Sunshine")
' repeat for Feb & Mar.

a2013(1) = InputBox("Please enter the total sunshine for January 2013", "Sunshine")
' repeat for Feb & Mar.

End Sub
```